# How do I use global a global variable containing a boolean to change other variable in google sheets script?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I am creating a little dummy spreadsheet and I would like to use a variable pointing to a `boolean`, which will be changed according to some logic, then use this boolean to change another `var`, like we do with `js` coding for the `web`

In case `partialDel()` runs, I wanna set `range` to `true` and then, when `addForm` runs, to change the `range` `variable` in case `range` property is set to `true`.

```
//I set the property here
PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('range', false);

function partialDel() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("UMS - Volumetria");
  sheet.insertRowBefore(11);
  sheet.getRange(11,2).setValue("Item:");
  sheet.insertRowBefore(13);
  sheet.getRange(13,2).setValue("Quantidade:");
  sheet.getRange(13,6).setValue("de");
  sheet.getRange("UMS - Volumetria!D13:E13").merge();
  sheet.getRange("UMS - Volumetria!G13:H13").merge().setBorder(null, null, true, null, false, true, "black", SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID);
  //here is where I set it to true
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('range', true)
}

  function addForm () {
  var range = "UMS - Volumetria!B9:L14"
//here is where I wanna check if the property is true 
  if(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('range') == true){
  range = "UMS - Volumetria!B9:L16" 
  }  
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const source = ss.getRange(range);
  const destSheet = ss.getSheetByName("UMS - Volumetria");  
  const destRange = destSheet.getRange(destSheet.getLastRow()+3,2);
  source.copyTo(destRange);
}
```

Comment: This code works for me as you have it written. `range` changes in `addForm` depending on whether `partialDel` ran first. Is there a specific problem you are having? Is `partialRange` part of the parent scope of these functions, as you have here in your example?

Comment: Thanks for replying me back here. I have no knowledge regarding google scripts, so I am not having a nice time here haha. Well, ```addForm``` and ```partialDel``` are placed inside distinct buttons in the spreadsheet. What I have noticed is that the variable I had set previously does not persist in between the function calls.

Comment: the order is that in case there is a partial delivery on the form inside this spreadsheet, the user will press ```partialDel``` first, then add forms using ```addForm```. When ```addForm``` is called, the ```var``` set is reacriated.

Comment: So I have discovered ```PropertiesService.getScriptProperties()```. I had read that this is more indicated in case I wanna persist some ```state``` in the script. But it still does not work when I run the ```if``` statement. I have updated my code above

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by changing the `if` statement `syntax`.

Somehow in google script, comparing data with `booleans` did not work for me. So I just checked the `truish` value of `range`.

old code: `if(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('range') === true)`

new code: `if(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('range'))`

```
//PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('range', false);

function partialDel() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("UMS - Volumetria");
  sheet.insertRowBefore(11);
  sheet.getRange(11,2).setValue("Item:");
  sheet.insertRowBefore(13);
  sheet.getRange(13,2).setValue("Quantidade:");
  sheet.getRange(13,6).setValue("de");
  sheet.getRange("UMS - Volumetria!D13:E13").merge();
  sheet.getRange("UMS - Volumetria!G13:H13").merge().setBorder(null, null, true, null, false, true, "black", SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID);
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('range', true)
}

  function addForm () {
  let range = "UMS - Volumetria!B9:L14" 
  if(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('range')){
  range = "UMS - Volumetria!B9:L16" 
  }  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();    
  const source = ss.getRange(range);
  const destSheet = ss.getSheetByName("UMS - Volumetria");  
  const destRange = destSheet.getRange(destSheet.getLastRow()+3,2);
  source.copyTo(destRange);
}
```